# how to drop duplicates and dcast pandas dataframe with comma separated values

Tags: pandas

I have following dataframe in pandas

```
  tank      nozzle
  1         1
  1         1
  1         2
  1         3
  1         1
  2         2
  2         1
  2         1
  2         2
  2         2
  2         1
  2         3
  2         2
```

I want following output

```
  tank      nozzle
  1         1,2,3
  2         1,2,3
```

Nozzle should be unique nos. 
How can I do it in pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert column `nozzle` to strings, [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with `join`:

```
df['nozzle'] = df['nozzle'].astype(str)
df1 = df.drop_duplicates().groupby('tank')['nozzle'].apply(','.join).reset_index()
print (df1)
   tank nozzle
0     1  1,2,3
1     2  2,1,3
```

Alternative solution with lambda function:

```
df1 = (df.drop_duplicates()
       .groupby('tank')['nozzle']
       .apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str)))
       .reset_index())
```

For lists:

```
df1 = df.drop_duplicates().groupby('tank')['nozzle'].apply(list).reset_index()
print (df)
   tank     nozzle
0     1  [1, 2, 3]
1     2  [2, 1, 3]
```